# First index wont populate correct amount of times

Tags: javascript

I'll preface this by saying, this is by no means the DRYest code out there. I am trying to return a string that shows how many times each letter shows up in the string by using an asterisk (*). My logic seems to be working for all letters, except for the first letter in the string. I can't for the life of me figure out why. Any ideas?

```
    let newCity = city.toLowerCase().split('');
    console.log(newCity);
    let newArr = [];
    let duplicate = '';
    let invis = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < newCity.length; i++) {
        if (
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i]) === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*') === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':**') === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':***') === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':****') === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*****') === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':******') === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*******') === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':********') === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*********') === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':**********') === -1 &&
            newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':***********') === -1
        ) {
            newArr.push(newCity[i] + ':*');
        } else if (newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':**') > 0) {
            duplicate = newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':**');
            newArr[duplicate] = newCity[i] + ':***';
        } else if (newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':***') > 0) {
            duplicate = newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':***');
            newArr[duplicate] = newCity[i] + ':****';
        } else if (newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':****') > 0) {
            duplicate = newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':****');
            newArr[duplicate] = newCity[i] + ':*****';
        } else if (newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*****') > 0) {
            duplicate = newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*****');
            newArr[duplicate] = newCity[i] + ':******';
        } else if (newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':******') > 0) {
            duplicate = newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':******');
            newArr[duplicate] = newCity[i] + ':*******';
        } else if (newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*******') > 0) {
            duplicate = newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*******');
            newArr[duplicate] = newCity[i] + ':********';
        } else if (newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':********') > 0) {
            duplicate = newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':********');
            newArr[duplicate] = newCity[i] + ':*********';
        } else if (newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*********') > 0) {
            duplicate = newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*********');
            newArr[duplicate] = newCity[i] + ':**********';
        } else if (newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':**********') > 0) {
            duplicate = newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':**********');
            newArr[duplicate] = newCity[i] + ':***********';
        } else {
            duplicate = newArr.indexOf(newCity[i] + ':*');
            newArr[duplicate] = newCity[i] + ':**';
        }
    }
    if (newArr.indexOf(' :*') > 0) {
        invis = newArr.indexOf(' :*');
        newArr.splice(invis, 1);
    }
    let newVal = newArr.join();
    console.log(newVal); 
}`
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's because first letter has **indexOf == 0** and you always check if **indexOf is > 0**.
You are missing first position.

Answer (score 2):

As @Astor suggested you are missing the first index

But please consider shorter code that is easier to read.

```js
function countChars(city) {
    let charCount = {};
    //split and iterate over the characters
    city.toLowerCase().split('').forEach(char =>{
        //assign char count to an object
        if(charCount[char]){
            charCount[char]++
        }else{
            charCount[char] = 1
        }
    });
    
    return Object.keys(charCount).map( char=> {
        // join characters and astrix counts
        return `${char}:${'*'.repeat(charCount[char])}`
    });
}


res = countChars("New York").join();
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it that's similar to @CWB's method, but a little more functional in how it works (reduce instead of forEach).

I also went ahead and added a `string.toLowerCase` in because counts would be based on the case by how it was originally defined and that seemed to be counter to the point.

```js
const city = 'test string';
const charCounter = (string, fillChar = '*') =>
  Object.entries( // Convert the created object into [key, value] pairs
    // Normalize the case, split it into parts, and reduce into the counts in an object
    string.toLowerCase().split('').reduce((groups, letter) => {
      groups[letter] = (groups[letter] || 0) + 1;
      return groups
    }, {})
    // Map the [key,value] pairs into the request format
  ).map(([letter, number]) =>
    `${letter}:${'*'.repeat(number)}`
  ).join(','); // join the pieces together

console.log(charCounter(city))
console.log(charCounter('New Orleans', '-'))
```